# Restart IIS sites at the "Connection" level from powershell

Tags: asp.net, windows, powershell, iis, sharepoint

How can I automatically restart a collection of IIS sites? I tried running the following commands which is able to restart all individual sites, but is not able to restart at the "connection" level in the IIS.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites | foreach { Stop-WebSite $_.Name; }
Stop-Service W3SVC
Start-Service W3SVC
Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites | foreach { Start-WebSite $_.Name; }
Start-WebAppPool "SharePoint Web Services Root"
```

The outcome I am looking for is, when all the commands are run, all the sites should have restarted (which they do), and also the "Start" and "Stop" buttons in the bottom screenshot should be greyed out and only the "Restart" button should be available. This would indicate to me that everything has indeed restarted.

[image: The IIS Connection is selected. Not site.]

[image: The "Start/Stop" buttons at the "connection" level is what I am trying to automate]

Comment: The powershell command you provide will restart all sites in IIS. I don't fully understand what you mean by IIS site collections?  What does it mean to restart at the "connection" level in IIS?

Comment: By that I mean the following: In the first screenshot just below the "Start Page", there is something that I have marked with red line (to hide the hostname). That, I believe, is a site collection -- I could be wrong about that. So when I select that, on the far right hand side of the IIS window I see the "Restart, Start and Stop" buttons which is shown in the 2nd screenshot. This particular restart is what I am trying to automate. I figured out the individual sites restart, but not this particular one.

Comment: This is not a site collection but is at the server level. Server-level properties are global to the entire server; all sites will inherit them. The command you provided will list the IIS sites, and then use a loop (foreach) to restart each obtained site. I think this has served its purpose.